# class selector refuses after append to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm appending loads of divs in a wrapper:

```
    var cubes    = [], 
    allCubes  = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < 380; i++) {
    var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)),
        randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    allCubes += '<div id="cube'+i+'" class="cube" style="position: absolute; border: 2px #000 solid; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 9px; height: 9px; z-index: -1"></div>';
}  

$('#wrapper').append(allCubes); // performance

for(var i = 0; i < 380; i++) {
 cubes.push($('#cube'+i));  
}
```

and then I would like to make them all draggable with `jQueryUI` and log their current position.

```
    var allc = $('.cube');
    allc.draggable().on('mouseup', function(i) {
        allc.each(function() {
        var nleft = $(this).offset().left;   
        var ntop = $(this).offset().top;
        console.log('cubes['+i+'].animate({ left:'+nleft+',top:'+ntop+'})');
        });
   });
```

Unfortunenately it does not work. They are neither draggable nor there comes up a log.

Thanks

Comment: scripting error `var cubes    = [],  allCubes  = '', for(` close the `var` statement `allCubes = '';`

Comment: Are you sure your second snippet is running after the previous one is executed? add a console.log in the first snippet to make sure.

Comment: @KevinB yep it runs after the first.

Comment: How are you confirming that. Sorry that i don't believe you, but it's common to expect that and something else entirely to happen when using ajax, if you are even using ajax. (i updated my previous comment)

Comment: Just add the console.logs. Add one after the 2nd snippet and one after the first. They should both happen, what i'm interested in is the order.

Comment: @KevinB I did, after the both loops and the draggable. Gives me all logs!

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/Q2msx/ that's why I'm skeptical. the problem *has* to be elsewhere.

Comment: @KevinB okay thats weird. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB is it possible to show you if I upload the site? Or is this not allowed because the OP is different?

Comment: Not really allowed because it would make the question useless once you fix the issue. I still think the problem is going to be related to the time at which each snippet is executed.

Comment: But, maybe it would allow us to give you an idea of why its happening, then you can update your question accordingly so that it will still be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @KevinB as stupid as it is, but I've tried it with an click before I was posting this question and it didnt work as well. The answer was: A div was layed over all cubes. Thanks anyways for your support, I really appreciate that.

Comment: thought you had it working here? http://jsfiddle.net/YFVXM/46/ and your console log doesn't take advantage of the array... Even if it did, you're basically making an array of 0-379, which you won't need an array to know. what was the assignment?

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 yes exactly, but if I mix it with my code it throws me jQuery Objects instead of numbers. But this OP is another one, I will ask it in my other post.